# Why is my nginx "rewrite" directive causing a redirection loop?

Tags: nginx, openresty, nginx-location

Given the following http block, nginx performs as expected.  That is, it will rewrite a URL such as `http://localhost/3ba48599-8be8-4326-8bd0-1ac6591c2041/` to `http://localhost/modif/3ba48599-8be8-4326-8bd0-1ac6591c2041/` and pass it to the uwsgi server.

```
http {    
    upstream frontend {
        server frontend:8000;
    }

    server {
        listen 8000;
        server_name localhost;

        root /www/;

        location ~* "^/([0-9a-f]{8}-([0-9a-f]{4}-){3}[0-9a-f]{12})/?$" {
            include uwsgi_params;
            set $uuid $1;
            if ($cookie_admin) {
              # if cookie exists, rewrite /<uuid> to /modif/<uuid> and pass to uwsgi
              rewrite / /modif/$uuid break;
              uwsgi_pass frontend;
            }
            content_by_lua_block {
                ngx.say("Ping!  You got here because you have no cookies!")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**However**, when I add another `location` block in the manner displayed blow, things fall appart and I get `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`.

```
http {
    # access_log /dev/stdout;  # so we can `docker log` it.

    upstream frontend {
        server frontend:8000;
    }

    server {
        listen 8000;
        server_name localhost;

        root /www/;

        location / {  # THIS MAKES EVERYTHING FALL APART :(
            uwsgi_pass frontend;
            include uwsgi_params;
        }

        location ~* "^/([0-9a-f]{8}-([0-9a-f]{4}-){3}[0-9a-f]{12})/?$" {
            include uwsgi_params;
            set $uuid $1;
            if ($cookie_admin) {
              # if cookie exists, rewrite /<uuid> to /modif/<uuid> and pass to uwsgi
              rewrite / /modif/$uuid break;
              uwsgi_pass frontend;
            }
            content_by_lua_block {
                ngx.say("Ping!  You got here because you have no cookies!")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What's going on here, exactly?  How can I fix this?

Comment: Which URL is causing the problem and what is it being redirected to?

Comment: @RichardSmith, any URL that is captured by the location regex (i.e. `/<UUIDv4>` will cause the error I've noted; I've provided an example of one such URL in the question.  I'm not sure how I can check where it's being redirected.  A cursory look at the chrome developer tools seems to suggest that it's being captured by the same location block over and over again (but again, I'm not sure).

Comment: I don't use chrome, but it looks like the resources -> headers tab should show you the details. The `location` field in the response header is what you are looking for. As your `nginx` configuration does not appear to generate external redirects, it's probably emanating from the upstream application.

Comment: @RichardSmith, it seems to be going back and forth between `/<uuid>` and `/modif/<uuid>`.  How would the involvement of the upstream application account for the change in behavior when the `location /` block is added?

Comment: This is just speculation - but before you added the new block a redirection to `/modif` would have resulted in a static file or a 404 error. If it's a resource file like JS or CSS, you might not notice the error.

Answer (score 0):

I see your Nginx is listening on port 8000, but your upstream server is at 'frontend', also on port 8000. If `frontend` resolves to the same server that Nginx is running on, then you've got a loop of proxy requests happening.

Comment: Thought of it too, but if so - it wouldn't have worked in the first config example